# Play Framework - Format Type @inputText

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have the following field in my form:

```
@inputText(
     empleadosForm("sueldo"),
     'placeholder -> "",
     '_label -> Messages("sueldo"),
     'class -> "form-control",
     '_size -> "col-md-6",
     'type -> "number",
     'required -> ""
    )
```

When i show a value greater than 9999999 (ex. 16000000), the field shows 16E7.
How can I do to show 16000000 instead of 16E7?

Comment: That's not scala, is it? Is it scala-js?

Comment: That appears to be a Twirl template in the Play Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was: In Java Form, i changed the field value to String, so, when i'm getting the object, i convert the value from double to string, and when i'm setting the value, i convert from string to double.

The problem of visualization is completely resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at the end of this section, it is possible to render your form field manually: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-forms/#constraints

```
  <input type="text" id="@{form("name").id}" name="@{form("name").label}" value="@{form("name").value}">
```

from this, you are basically left with the problem of displaying 16E7 as 16000000 in scala:

```
scala> val x = 16E7
x: Double = 1.6E8

scala> f"$x%.0f"
res9: String = 160000000
```